# Can I update a passkit QR automatically 15 mins after the user views it?

Tags: ios, passkit

If a user downloads a pass, can the QR be refreshed from the service on a short timeline, such as every 15 mins.

Our systems run out of codes very quickly, so the client needs to get a new code every 15 mins. That's fine on other media. Long term this will be solved by changing the length the codes so we don't run out so quickly, in the short term can this be achieved using passkit?

Answer (score 0):

You can send a push notification requesting that Wallet update your pass whenever you like, as described in the [Updating a Pass](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/PassKit_PG/Updating.html) documentation; note, though, that if you send too many pushes too close together, Wallet will start rate-limiting your updates to conserve the user’s battery and cellular-data usage. I don’t think the rate-limiting rules are documented anywhere (they’re mentioned briefly in the [2013 WWDC session](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2013/302/)), so you may have to do some experimenting to find out whether that update schedule is viable.

[image: update flow diagram]

As to “after the user views it”: no, there’s no API for that; you get one notification when the user first adds your pass to their library, and one when they either delete it or disable automatic updating for it. Assuming whatever scanning system you’re using is connected to your server, you might consider “the pass with this code was scanned” as an event that should trigger an update push to all passes with that code on them.